# how to create POST data in django python

Tags: python, django, post

I have a Django app where I'd like to create some POST data (namely to store whether or not I'm returning to the login screen for a failed login).  Anyone know how I can manipulate the request.POST QueryDict to store some more data? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I tried just request.POST['loginFail'] = True, but it tells me that the QueryDict is immutable.

Comment: Try `dict(request.POST)['loginFail'] = True`

Comment: Have you tried adding hidden fields to your html?

Comment: what are hidden fields and how would i use them to reach the effect of showing an error if the user has a failed login attempt?

Comment: You have to be more specific in your question. What fields (or a subset of them) you want to add to the QueryDict and how you want to store them.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: not very clear what you mean by "storing". POST data are data passed from the client to the server. Is it what you need to do ? Could you describe your login flow ?

Comment: I want to pass from my python script in views.py to the HTML template a boolean value so that I can determine whether or not to display a message indicating that an invalid login was used.

Comment: ok, so this is the other direction. The easiest seems to use the templating language https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **NEVER** modify `POST` data. What you can do instead, as a work around is:

```
post_dict = request.POST.copy()
```

Now you have access to `request.POST` as a local dictionary.

You can update the dictionary as:

```
post_dict.update('loginfailed', False)
```

Now, use this `post_dict` as a context variable sent into the template where you can do

```
{% if post_dict.login_failed %}
```

Or even simpler. Just send `{'login_failed': False}` in the context, so you can access it as

```
{% if login_failed %}
  {# do this #}
{% else %}
  {# do that #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the redirect from my authorization script back to the login page with the context dict?  I don't think that HttpResponseRedirect has a param for the context.

Comment: use `render` or `render_to_response` instead of `HttpResponseRedirect`